# Different Speech Engine with DialogFlow

Tags: integration, speech

Can I use a different speech engine with DialogFlow apps?  We have our own large vocabulary speech to text engine that we can customize, so we can prioritize vertical vocabularies that make more sense for a specific application.  Is there a way to integrate our speech engine into DialogFlow?  when I look at an integration offered, like Alexa, is the ability to create those integrations available to developers?

Comment: You can use open source dialogflow analogs then like Rasa NLP https://rasa.com